# A first-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A function $y=f(x)$ satisfies the first-order differential equation
$$y'(y-x+a)=b,\,\,\,x\in [0,1]$$
where $a\in (0,1)$ and $b>0$ are known constants.

It is more or less clear that the function has an affine solution $f(x)=x+(b-a)$, which is indeed the only affine function that satisfies the differential equation

However, it seems hard to pin down the general solution, which should be obtained in a systematic way rather than "guess-and-verify''. The special affine solution gives no hint for what the general solution should look like.

Can anyone give some suggestions/hints? Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$y'(y-x+a)=b,\,\,\,x\in [0,1]$$
$$y-x+a=bx'$$
This is a first order linear DE.

Answer (score 1):

After the change of variables
$$
u=y-x+a,\qquad u'=y'-1
$$
the equation becomes separable:
$$
(u'+1)u=b
$$
$$
u'=\frac{b}{u}-1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$y'=\frac{1}{y-x+a}$$
Let $y-x+a=v \implies y'-1=v'$, then the ODE is
$$v'=2/v-1\implies \int \frac{vdv}{2-v}=\int dx+C$$